# scanf doesn't stop with qt creator, with visual studio code works, i have the problem just with qt creator

Tags: c, scanf, qt-creator

scanf, getchar, fgets doesn't stop when enter is pressed with qt creator, with visual studio code works
where the problem ?

i don't want use visual or eclipse or another for work in c.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

char c;
printf("enter value : ");
fflush(stdout);
scanf(" %c", &c);
printf("%c", c);

return 0;
}
```

with visual studio code (works when enter is pressed) :

[image]

with qt creator (doesn't works scanf doesn't stop when enter is pressed):

[image]

and the manage kit :

[image]

in /usr/bin cmake and links gcc are there :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Your code works: try to enter a character and press enter. I guess you want not to have to press enter and have the key as they are pressed by the user ?

Comment: for me doesn't work, and i don't anderstand why, when i press enter scanf doesn't stop

Comment: do you use qt creator ?